# Continue doesn't seem to work in this simple Python function

Tags: python, continue

The function is supposed to take a string as its input and return (if all members of the string are digits) and integer version of that string. The string provided in this example is a 3 digit number. the function's for loop seems to only return the first digit only hence the continue may not be working as expected.

```
e = '484'

def resolving(e):
    for i, o in enumerate(e):

        if o in "0123456789":

            s = []
            s.append(o)
            i += 1

            continue
                
        elif o not in "0123456789":
            print(type(e))
            return e

    k = str(s)
    y = k.replace("'","").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","").replace(" ","")
    p = int(y)
    print(type(p))
    return p

print(resolving(e))
```

Comment: Every time you append something to `s`, you first set it to an empty list.  It will never contain more than one element.  Move the initialization outside of the loop.  And that `continue` is pointless, it does exactly what the code would do anyway, as there is nothing further that would happen during the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: Actually creating the list `s` is not necessary as you will end up with `e` again after transforming it back to a string. Also I don't see why you use enumerate instead of directly iterating through the string.

Comment: Add some simple debugging print statements -- you will soon see that it's your code that doesn't work, not the `continue` statement.

Comment: And this is why you don't only look at test cases where the first digit is the same as the last digit...

Comment: Thanks guys but the reason why I had to put the conversion of the list 's' to a string in the  function because i need to feed the output into a return statement. Also I tried using the error handling statements( try, except and finally) but wasn't behaving as expected. Hopefully with your combined examples, I will figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of completely missing the point of what you're trying to do, this entire function could just be:

```
def resolve(e):
    """If e is convertible to an int, return its int value; 
    otherwise print its type and return the original value."""
    try:
        return int(e)
    except ValueError:
        print(type(e))
        return e
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you make the list in the loop. Just make it outside the loop. Also instead of `str(s)` which makes a string representation of the list use `str.join` as it will join all the elements of the list into a string. Also there is no need for the continue statement. As the elif won't run if the if is True.

```
for i, o in enumerate(e):
    s = []
    if o in "0123456789":
        s.append(o)
    else:
        print(type(e))
        return e
k = ''.join(s)
p = int(y)
return p
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `return` in there, so the first time you hit a non-numeric character you're going to return that character and exit.  As written, the continue won't do anything since the following `elif` won't be hit by any character that sends you down the first branch of the if statement.

Comment: Hmm, first sentence is irrelevant to the question, second sentence doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

If you regard only the integers of a string as its integer version, you can use `isnumeric()` check:

```
def resolve(e)
    return int(''.join([i for i in e if i.isnumeric()]))
```